# Is there a material that returns to original, curled form when straightened?

Tags: materials

Is there a material that 'wants' to be curled up but can be straightened an indefinite number of times without failing?

Comment: Like shape memory alloys?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape-memory_alloy

Answer (score 3):

There is nickel , titanium alloy Nitinol. I don't remember much about it except it has unique mechanical properties.

Comment: Nitinol is an example of an alloy with shape memory and superelasticity properties. I don't know much about its uses either.

Comment: I thought everyone interested in engineering had made a stiquito: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiquito